# Session in ini_set not working as expected

Tags: php, session

I have set the `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session.cookie_lifetime`. As documented on the site, it **gc_maxlifetime** should set the maximum session time and setting **cookie_lifetime** to **0** should destroy the session. But its not working as expected.

I have following code in my php file :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); // For testing I keep it for 10 sec
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
session_start();
if ($_GET['set']) {
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
}

if ($_GET['delete']) {
  session_destroy();
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Its not working as expected. Its not destroying the session after an hour and on closing browser as well.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php `The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.`

Answer (score 1):

Setting *session.cookie_lifetime* to 0 doesn't destroy a session, it tells the browser to discard the cookie when closed.

The *session.gc_maxlifetime* setting is a bit more tricky. I does indeed set the time after a session is considered to be expired and therefore deleted. However, that doesn't happen immediately and in fact, depending on other settings - it may not happen at all.
What happens is, you also have the *session.gc_probability* and *session.gc_divisor* settings, which together form the "chance" for the session garbage collector to run - this is explained in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor).
It is only when the GC runs that *session.gc_maxlifetime* comes into play and existing session's timestamps are compared to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to do this sort of thing globally in php.ini, because all scripts have a chance (based on gc_probability / gc_divisor) to trigger the garbage collection and **they will do so based on their own current settings**.

If this is not possible, a workaround is to set a custom [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) in your script.